# Is it possible to invoke a function outside the "parent" function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I wondered if it was possible to invoke a function outside its "parent" function:

```
var $element = $( '.element' );

function myFunction( element ) {
    var width;

    function onResize() {
        width = element.width();
    }
    onResize();
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
    onResize();
});
```

The console returns: **Uncaught ReferenceError: onResize is not defined**
I thought it was possible to define it outside the function as for variables:

```
var variable;

$( window ).resize() {
    variable = 1;
});
$( window ).resize();
```

how can I define it also outside the main function?

Comment: The "parent" concept you're looking for is called "scope". You can't use a variable outside of its scope.

Comment: Though the variable is global I can use it outside it's scope

Comment: No, you can use it in the global scope, and in closures that capture that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols declared within a function are scoped to that function (and any nested functions), so they're not accessible from outside of that function, not least because, since each call to the function creates a new version of those symbols' values, using one outside of the function would raise the question of *which one* to use.

But functions are objects, and so you can get references to them, and if you can get references to them you can call them. The usual way you'd get a reference to the `onResize` created by a specific call to `MyFunction` would be to use it from code within the `MyFunction`, or for `MyFunction` to *return* a reference to the `onResize` created by that call to it:

```
function myFunction( element ) {
    var width;

    function onResize() {
        width = element.width();
    }
    onResize();

    return onResize;
}

$(window).resize(MyFunction());
```